# tabularx adding half column

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

tabularx with a \newcolumntype and \multicolumn adds another incomplete column to the right side

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}  X}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{ |s|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{Item}\\
    \hline
    a & b\\
    \hline 
    c & d \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

where does this come from and how can I remove it?

[image: table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have two `X` columns, one of them being half as wide as the other, it is not a coefficient of `0.5`you have to choose, but `2` coefficients such that `their sum is 2`, one of them being half the other. In other words $2/3$  and $4/3$.

For the multicolumn (which is not recommended here), use the `l` specifier, not `X`. The `X` specifier leads to a multicolumn that is half the table wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.667\hsize\arraybackslash} X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=1.333\hsize\arraybackslash} X}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{ |s| >{\arraybackslash}Y|}
    \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Item}\\
    \hline
    a & b\\
    \hline
    c & d \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if I had 3 columns, would the sum have to be 3, too? and so on?

also why is multicolumn not recomended and what alterantiv would be better?

Comment: Yes, the sum of the coefficients must be equal to the number of columns. `\multicolumn` is not recommended in case you have X type columns of different widths, as here. I don't know why, I suppose calculations of the package might be perturbated. It's written in § 4.3, p. 3 of the documentation, which adds this rule may be broken if you know what you're doing. The alternative would be to use  a `p{…}` column, with a width  approximately.determined.